# Escape sequence string processing in android

Tags: android, escaping

I have a string variable in my android ap which contains some url http://www.google.com. The string variable is declared as shown below:

```
String html="<a href="http://www.google.com"></a>";
```

But there is an error saying that I have to put (semicolon); after the ***a href="***. But actually I want the entire line content ie

***(href="http://www.google.com")*** in the string variable. How can it be achieved?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's what the use of escape character's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**doubles quotes needs to escaped.**

try below one

`String html="<a href='http://www.google.com'></a>"`;

else

`String html= "<a href= \"http://www.google.com\"></a>"`;

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape every `"` with `\` if you want to put it in one String.

For example:

```
String html="<a href=\"http://www.google.com\"></a>";
```

If you don't do this, compiler assumes, that you end this String after `href=` and tries to understand what `http://www.google.com` means in `Java` ;)